# Why is my load image, and my screen.blit function not working?

Tags: image

I am a beginner to python in pygame.
I started to make complicated games myself.
Like space shooter, car race etc...
I am using IDLE, python3.9.0 version to make these games
But unfortunately, my screen.blit function is not working.
Why is it showing a invalid syntax error?!
Why is my load function not working?!
Here’s my part of the code:

```
space_background = pygame.image.load(“os.path.join(space_background.jpg”)

for x in range:
     (pygame.display.space_background.get_width(None, 1500)
for y in range:
     (pygame.display.space_background.get_hieght(None, 1005)
     screen.blit(space_background, (x,y)
```

Error for my load image:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “D:\Data_folder\caption.py”, line 12, in <module>
    space_background = pygame.image.load(“os.path.join(space_background.jpg”)
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
```

For my blit error:
It is highlighting my ‘s’ word in screen.blit function and throwing an syntax error: invalid syntax
Can someone please help me about this problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

You... can't do this. I'm pretty sure your image file is not "os.path.join(space_background.jpg".

```
space_background = pygame.image.load("os.path.join(space_background.jpg")
```

Just writing

```
space_background = pygame.image.load("space_background.jpg")
```

should work.

As for all the syntax errors, you have a bunch of strange misplaced parentheses.